# hay alguna funcion en microsoft SQL server para poder insertar los datos de una tabla de forma dinamica?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una consigna pero no encuentro el comando correcto para realizar mi task, por lo que no tengo codigo que compartir por eso necesito ayuda; Tengo 4 tablas con columnas diferentes, comparten columnas iguales como ID, Fecha, Monitoreo y ID de monitoreo.

```
Fecha  | Monitoreo | IDmonitoreo |  column1  | column2  | column3
03-Feb  Lapras      1               azul       bajo       roca
03-Feb  Lapras      2               rojo       mediano    piedra
03-Feb  jolteon     3               verde      alto       gravilla

Fecha  | Monitoreo | IDmonitoreo |  column4  | column5  | column6
03-Feb  Lapras      4               trompeta   fuego      cielo
03-Feb  Lapras      5               tambor     viento     tierra
03-Feb  jolteon     6               violin     agua       mar

Fecha  | Monitoreo | IDmonitoreo |  column7  | column8  | column9
03-Feb | Lapras    | 7           |  perro    | pollo    | gas
03-Feb | Lapras    | 8           |  gato     | gallo    | solido
03-Feb | jolteon   | 9           |  ave      | vaca     | liquido

Fecha  | Monitoreo | IDmonitoreo |  column10  | column11 | column12
03-Feb | Lapras    | 10          |  termita   | frio     | trueno
03-Feb | Lapras    | 11          |  abeja     | caliente | relampago
03-Feb | jolteon   | 12          |  hormiga   | tibio    | rayo
```

y quiero convertirlo a algo asi

```
Fecha  | Monitoreo | IDmonitoreo |  Nombre de columna  | Valor  | 
03-Feb  Lapras      1               column1             Azul
03-Feb  Lapras      1               column2             bajo
03-Feb  Lapras      1               column3             roca
03-Feb  Lapras      2               column1             rojo
03-Feb  Lapras      2               column2             mediano
03-Feb  Lapras      2               column3             piedra
03-Feb  jolteon     3               column1             verde
03-Feb  jolteon     3               column2             alto
03-Feb  jolteon     3               column3             gravilla
03-Feb  Lapras      4               column4             trompeta
03-Feb  Lapras      4               column5             fuego
03-Feb  Lapras      4               column6             cielo
03-Feb  Lapras      5               column4             tambor
03-Feb  Lapras      5               column5             violin
03-Feb  Lapras      5               column6             agua
03-Feb  jolteon     6               column4             violin
03-Feb  jolteon     6               column5             agua
03-Feb  jolteon     6               column6             mar
03-Feb  Lapras      7               column7             perro
03-Feb  Lapras      7               column8             pollo
03-Feb  Lapras      7               column9             gas
03-Feb  Lapras      8               column7             gato
03-Feb  Lapras      8               column8             gallo
03-Feb  Lapras      8               column9             solido
03-Feb  jolteon     9               column7             ave
03-Feb  jolteon     9               column8             vaca
03-Feb  jolteon     9               column9             liquido
03-Feb  Lapras      10              column10            termita
03-Feb  Lapras      10              column11            frio
03-Feb  Lapras      10              column12            trueno
03-Feb  Lapras      11              column10            abeja
03-Feb  Lapras      11              column11            caliente
03-Feb  Lapras      11              column12            relampago
03-Feb  jolteon     12              column10            hormiga
03-Feb  jolteon     12              column11            tibio
03-Feb  jolteon     12              column12            rayo
```

tengo la idea de usar Pivot, pero necesito una mente mas brillante
alguien puede ayudarme con consejos?

no puedo unir estas tablas, aunque tienen muchas columnas en las que puedo hacer el JOIN, tienen ids diferentes por lo que las colapsaria en ves de unirlas 1:1

Comment: El título dice Insert y en tu pregunta dices que quieres un select con Join?

Comment: pero no esta en tono de pregunta esa parte, y no menciono Select en ninguna parte, eso ultimo del Join es una aclaracion.

Comment: Si mencionaste Pivot es porque es un select.

Comment: es lo que se me ocurre :/ mas quiero saber como le harian, ideas o consejos para poder crear la tabla asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad necesitas hacer un [`UNPIVOT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15), es decir transformar columnas en filas:

```
select  U.Fecha,
        U.Monitoreo,
        U.IDMonitoreo,
        U.Columna,
        U.Valor
    FROM @Ejemplo
    UNPIVOT
    (
      Valor
      FOR Columna IN (column1, column2, column3)
    ) U
    ORDER BY U.IDMonitoreo
```

La sintaxis es relativamente sencilla, hay que indicar en el `in` los nombres de columna que vamos a exportar. `Columna` y `Valor` son los nombres que daremos a las nuevas columnas.

Comment: Mil gracias, me funciono bastante y me ayudo a ver el problema de otra forma!